# Update Single Hash in SubscribeToMore Instead of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, graphql, react-apollo

How to update single hash. When I try to change value in hash it does not change. As hash is read only but when I do in array it works. i have only hash in current scenario.

```
 subscribeToMore(
  {
   document: postUpdated,
   updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {

   if (subscriptionData.data.postUpdated) {

      console.log("------Updated hash------",subscriptionData.data.postUpdated);    

      previousResult.property.water_heater = subscriptionData.data.postUpdated.water_heater; 

    // readonly unable to assign

     return subscriptionData;
  }else{
    return previousResult;
    }

   },
  }
 )
```

But with this code it works

```
subscribeToMore(
    {
      document: postUpdated,
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {
        previousResult.posts = previousResult.posts.map((post) => {
          if(post._id === subscriptionData.data.postUpdated._id) {
            return subscriptionData.data.postUpdated
          } else {
            return post
          }
        })
        return previousResult
      },
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you are mutating `previousResult.property` and in the second you are mutating `previousResult`.

I think it will work if you do

```
subscribeToMore({
  document: postUpdated,
  updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {
    if (subscriptionData.data.postUpdated) {
      console.log("------Updated hash------", subscriptionData.data.postUpdated);    

      previousResult.property = {
        ...previousResult.property,
        water_heater = subscriptionData.data.postUpdated.water_heater; 
      }
    }
    return previousResult;
  },
})
```